# A special number

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Here is a nice puzzle from my friend.

Can you find a number that is a product of two consecutive primes and when multiplied by its own reversal produces a palindrome? The answer may surprise you. No computers please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't use programming but used a calculator. I think the answer is

> **11021** = 103 × 107, where 11021 × 12011 = 132373231 is a palindrome.

First I observed that

> if the resulting palindrome has an even number of digits, it must be a multiple of 11, so the only candidates were 7 × 11 and 11 × 13, neither of which worked. 
>  Note that *n* is a multiple of 11 if and only if its reverse is a multiple of 11, which can be seen from the divisibility rule by 11: *n* is a multiple of 11 iff its alternating sum of digits is. E.g. 10417 is a multiple of 11 because 1 - 0 + 4 - 1 + 7 = 11, and so is 71401 because 7 - 1 + 4 - 0 + 1 = 11.

Therefore

> the palindrome (*n* times mirror of *n*) must have an odd number of digits, which can happen only if both the first and last digits of *n* are low.

So I started searching for

> the possible values of n, where the primes are a power of 10 plus a small number. I jumped right away to 101 × 103, then tried 103 × 107, which worked.

---

After finding this answer, I decided to check if there are other possible answers (of course using a program).

Turns out there are two more:

> 13 × 17 = **221**, 221 × 122 = 26962
>  
>  43 × 47 = **2021**, 2021 × 1202 = 2429242
>  
>  Other than the three already mentioned, there are **no solutions until 1,000,000th prime.** Note that all digits are 2 or lower in all the solutions.

The program used:

> [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), which has enough built-ins for the job:
>
> ```
> 1000000 nprimes [ * ] 2clump-map
> [ dup 10 >base reverse dec> * 10 >base dup reverse = ] filter .
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU67DsIwDNz7FTcjUbWMRXRFXVgQU8UQUvch2jQ4DoKvD6E8PFine/jcKi0zh9OxOuwLdDx7O5gupYewcrgSGxoxKemXlVrFjviLeZjIJY5unowmB8sk8oy0EWyT6lDAaVai@5Bny8B8MqixwhkbPfrJridlkxqNt8gzlBflCEx3ikVoSJfR@uffpp@2ixfaYZT4ThrCCw)

I still like my original answer the most, because

> it can be nicely divided into chunks of digits:
>
>  132 = 11 × 12
>  373 = 121 + 252 = 11 × 11 + 12 × 21
>  231 = 21 × 11
>  → 132,373,231 = 11,021 × 12,011

Comment: This is correct! Well done. For me the second smallest answer was a surprise.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yeah, that was a small surprise to me too, because it was out of the range I was searching in (primes slightly larger than powers of 10). That said, it might have been feasible to find all three by hand if I noticed earlier that (3,7) is the only last-digit combination that produces 1 as the last digit. (There are (1,1) and (9,9) too, but they don't appear up to 120).

Comment: "it must be a multiple of 11, so the only candidates were 7 × 11 and 11 × 13" Why?

Comment: @tsh Because a number is a multiple of 11 iff its reverse is a multiple of 11.